# Call for voting posse: synonym [open-game-license] to [ogl]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just noticed that we have the (older, more well-established) [ogl](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ogl) tag as well as the (newer, used on only two questions) [open-game-license](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-game-license) tag. I went to the [ogl](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ogl) tag and suggested the other as a synonym, so [go vote it up and make it happen](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/ogl/synonyms)!

Before debate ensues about which should actually be the tag and which the synonym: our usual policy is to use the more common term within the wider community, and "OGL" is used overwhelmingly more than the full "Open Game License", just like "D&D 4e" gives us [dnd-4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-4e) because it's used overwhelmingly instead of the longer version. That seems clear enough to me that I don't think it needs discussion, but it's possible there's a flaw in that reasoning.

As a side note, the tag wiki text in [open-game-license](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-game-license) is excellent, so I replaced the tag wiki text in [ogl](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ogl) with it. Props to [@MattThomason](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/9293/matt-thomason) for that text!

Comment: Who is allowed to do that? Just tells me that I don't have enough votes on the tag to be allowed to vote.

Comment: @Tridus: "Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms." There's a list of eligible users here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/ogl/topusers

Comment: Not gonna lie, I just spent 5 minutes trying to figure out how to vote.